# accented characters in latex

Tags: latex

I am writing a document in spanish, and I'm trying to add 'í' to the word
Montréal.However if I put the i like this: \'{e} in the code below, I just get a space instead of the é. Why is this not working?

```
   \begin{tabbing}%
   \hspace{2.3in}\= \hspace{2.6in}\= \kill % set up two tab positions          
   {\bf Engineer}\> Panagro S.A.\> Summers  2004-2010\\
                          \>Montréal, Colombia
   \end{tabbing}\vspace{-15pt}
```

Also I might add that when I try putting Montréal outside of the tabbing block, it works fine.

Ted

Answer (score 6):

> ### Tabbing environment
>
> Some of the accent marks used in running text have other uses in the tabbing environment. In that case they can be created with the following command:
>
> - \a' for an acute accent
> - \a` for a grave accent
> - \a= for a macron accent

source: [LaTeX/Accents at Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Accents#Tabbing_environment)

Answer (score 1):

Related question on [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/how-to-type-special-accented-letters-in-latex) with a great solution to accented characters.

Save your file as UTF-8 and put

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

in your preamble.

Then you can just type the characters normally into your source file.

Or, use XeLaTeX which accepts UTF-8 input natively. In that case you need to add

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

to your preamble.

If your text editor doesn't support UTF-8 encoded files, you should probably get another editor. But if you're stuck with one, you can also use:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % for PCs
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} % for Macs
```

and save the files in the default encoding for your machine.

Thanks to [Alan Munn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2693/alan-munn) for the solution!